# Inequalities $- x^2 - (1/2) x - 5 < 0$ ; why is $x > 5/2$?

Tags: inequality, quadratics

Question :

$$\text{ find the set of values of }x \text{ for which } $$

$$10 + x - 2x^2 < 0$$

Answer :

$$x < -2$$

$$x > 2\frac{1}{2}$$

---

EDIT - thanks for the responses. To try and highlight what it is I'm not understanding :

I have

$$(x+2)\left(x-\frac{5}{2}\right) > 0 $$

I now understand why this is greater than zero after factoring out the negative sign, the same way that

$$-30 < -5  $$

$$30 > 5 $$

However I'm still unsure about why we chose the answers.

As explained by mathlove -

$$\iff "x+2\gt 0\ \text{and}\ x-\frac 52\gt0"\ \text{or}\ "x+2\lt 0\ \text{and}\ x-\frac 52\lt0"$$

$$\iff x\gt \frac 52\ \ \text{or}\ \ x\lt -2.$$

I don't really see what it is that made us choose the $x < -2 $ rather than $x>-2$.... from the options above it looks like it could have been either?

Even without these options that I hadn't even considered I'm unsure about the $\frac{5}{2}$ mainly...

I'll try and demonstrate my working because I'm struggling to use words -

so from

$$(x+2)(x-\frac{5}{2}) > 0 $$

I know that

$$x-2 > 0$$

$$x+\frac{5}{2}> 0$$

So when I move the negative two over the other side of the inequality sign I change the direction

$$ x < -2 $$

and then when I effect the 5/2 I'm wrong, I feel it should go

$$x + \frac{5}{2} > 0$$

Arhh, I think a penny might have dropped -

It's because the 5/2 is positive... so

$$ x + \frac{5}{2} > 0 $$

then

$$ x < -\frac{5}{2} $$

Soo

$$ x > -\frac{5}{2}$$

is that right?

Answer (score 1):

we can rewrite the inequality in the following form
$10+x-2x^2<0$ is equivalent to
$x^2-\frac{1}{2}x-5>0$
$(x+2)\left(x-\frac{5}{2}\right)>0$
from here we obtain
$x<-2$ or $x>\frac{5}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$10+x-2x^2\lt 0\iff \frac{10+x-2x^2}{-2}\color{red}{\gt}\frac{0}{-2}\iff x^2-\frac{1}{2}x-5\gt0$$
and that
$$\left(x+2\right)\left(x-\frac 52\right)\gt0$$
$$\iff "x+2\gt 0\ \text{and}\ x-\frac 52\gt0"\ \text{or}\ "x+2\lt 0\ \text{and}\ x-\frac 52\lt0"$$
$$\iff x\gt \frac 52\ \ \text{or}\ \ x\lt -2.$$

Comment: Thanks, I'm not too sure what the " marks stand for...? Aren't they usually minutes / seconds in degrees and that? thanks

Comment: I've not seen them before, I'm guessing they just means "is equal to"... It was the quotation parts that I wasn't too sure about, unless they're just a bit of latex that hasn't been rendered? cheers

Comment: @learner: I just used "$\cdots$" to separate that into two cases : The case when $x+2\gt0\ \text{and}\ x-\frac 52\gt 0$ or the case when $x+2\lt 0\ \text{and}\ x-\frac 52\lt 0$.

Comment: I've written this out, I'm still not really seeing what makes one decide that the answer is $x < -2 $ or $x > \frac{5}{2}$ rather than $x>-2$ or $x<\frac{5}{2}$ :(

Comment: @learner: You understand we have $\left(x+2\right)\left(x-\frac 52\right)\color{red}{\gt}0$, don't you? If so, what is the step that you cannot understand in my answer?

Comment: cheers mathlove - I've updated the OP because I can edit that... I'm still slightly unsure about the part where you have $or x+2 < 0 \text{ and } x - \frac{5}{2} < 0$.... I never even considered those values... but for the ones that I did consider, hopefully the OP edit demonstrates that a bit?

Comment: @learner: For the case when $x+2\gt 0\ \text{and}\ x-\frac 52\gt 0$, $x+2\gt 0$ is equivalent to $x\color{red}{\gt} -2$ and $x-\frac 52\gt 0$ is equivalent to $x\gt \frac 52$. So, since we have $x\gt -2\ \text{and}\ x\gt \frac 52$, we have $x\gt\frac 52$. You can do the same thing for the second case to get $x\lt -2$.

Comment: What I was referring to was the way that you have two sets of values, separated by the or : $ x + 2> 0 \text{ and } x - \frac{5}{2} > 0 \text{ .....OR..... } x + 2 < 0 \text{ and } x - \frac{5}{2} < 0$... the second set of values I never thought of.

Comment: @learner: Since $(x+2)\left(x-\frac 52\right)$ is positive, either that the both is positive or that the both is negative. I used this fact. Is that what you are asking?

Answer (score 0):

You begin with $$-2x^2+x+10 < 0.$$

You divided by $-2$. But when you divide by a negative number, you must switch the inequality. Think of it like adding terms to either side:

$$-2x^2+x+10 + \color{red}{2x^2 -x  - 10} < 0 + \color{red}{2x^2 -x -10}\\
0 < 2x^2-x-10 \\
2x^2 -x-10 > 0
$$

Comment: Argh how silly... I was trying to work this out, I got a quadratic and multiplied it by negative 1 then compared them for equality in Wolfram and they were equal, so I thought I could factor out the negative 1 without a problem as long as it was equal to zero... This is clearly wrong! Thanks for the help, I'm going to look at why the equality sign changes direction.

Comment: It's an *inequality*, not an equality. As for why the sign changes direction when dividing/multiplying by negative numbers, re-read my post. I add the red terms to both sides of the inequality. On the left, they annihilate the black terms. Observe the result!

Comment: Thanks, I've been through them, when it get's to the stage in the quadratic where it's been factored `(x+2)(x-5/2)` and we can see that x = -2 and x = 5/2.... the inequality remains the same way with the x = -2, it goes to x < -2..... but with the x = 5/2 it flips to x > 5/2 ... I'm not sure why that is, what it is that indicates that x is greater than 5/2 here... cheers, sorry for the slowness.

Comment: Don't look at the factorization. The inequality switches as soon as you multiply by $-1$. Then you factor. Then your result gives you what you want.